# Is it possible to lighten PhoneGap+jQuery apps?

Tags: cordova

I've just created a very simple web app (Hello World and two links) with PhoneGap + jQuery, and the APK file size is 2.0 Mb.

I wonder if this a regular size of a simple PhoneGap+jQuery app, and if there is any tip to lighten it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do, but they won't make a whole heap of difference.

1. Use the minified versions of any libraries you are using (jQuery in this case)
2. Minify your own code before you build
3. Download resources such as images at first startup rather than 'bake them in' (just that is just deferring the problem)

Other than that, you could write simpler apps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the "fat" that you mention about comes from the PhoneGap itself and any native implementation that is required by the plugins that you include in the applications.

The JavaScript functionality that you use in your app is relatively small in the application bundle. You can minimise them and further reduce the size but  considering that they are bundled and not loaded remotely, this step might not have such a dramatic impact. However, as these libraries are interpreted at runtime, the run-time memory requirements can explode easily.

So, in short, be more worried of how much RAM you use than how big the app bundle is...

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this phonegap app](http://novasoftware.com/download/phonegap/helplessmaze.aspx), its size is less than 1MB. It's developed in [this phonegap framework](http://cordova.codeplex.com/), not jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove unused plugins from your config xml file and remove related code from the cordova js file.

Hope this helps ! Bye !

Answer (score 0):

Best thing you can do is remove splass screens.
My app doesn't have splass screens, it's weight is 469k, and I use jquery mobile